# Spotfire Javascript Output Disappeared

Tags: javascript, html, spotfire, justgage

I have a small javascript in a spotfire Text area. It was working as designed. I saved and closed spotfire. On re-open it does not show at all. My code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
resource = [
  "//cdn.rawgit.com/toorshia/justgage/master/raphael-2.1.4.min.js",
  "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.8/justgage.js"
]

//add scripts to head
$.getScript(resource[0], function() {
  $.getScript(resource[1], init)
})

var init = function() {
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    customSectors: [{
        "lo": 0,
        "hi": 89.999,
        "color": "#f05050"
      },
      {
        "lo": 90,
        "hi": 92.999,
        "color": "#DD7502"
      },
      {
        "lo": 93,
        "hi": 100,
        "color": "#41c572"
      }
    ],
    levelColorsGradient: false
  });
  //refresh gauge when calcvalue changes
  $(calcValue).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    g.refresh($(this).text())
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id=calcValue><SpotfireControl id="3321e4c9003142ad83fdb753e6f66605" />
</span>
<DIV id=gauge></DIV>
```

Comment: example needs jquery also

Comment: what is `init`?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry I was playing around trying to get it to work and changed `init = function()` to `window.onload = function()`

Comment: I tried to have 3 different charts using the same code above with different values. When refreshing the browser in spotfire I can not get it to show the background of the gauge but all messed up see [img](http://imgur.com/Ve8E0Te)

Comment: and the console will show you the error when you fix the init and the missing jQuery. Something about the gradient....

Comment: @epascarello I have not been getting any errors with this code. I have tried your code and still no errors, but still not showing correctly. I have removed all extra js scripts and left only 1 until it is working. see [img](http://imgur.com/a/fW73B)

I have also tried different resource sources to no avail.

Comment: `{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}` right there in the console when I hit the run button in the question above. When you look at the developer console it has the script error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the examples, it should be:

```js
resource = [
  "//cdn.rawgit.com/toorshia/justgage/master/raphael-2.1.4.min.js",
  "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.8/justgage.js"
]

//add scripts to head
$.getScript(resource[0], function() {
  $.getScript(resource[1], init)
})

var init = function() {
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    customSectors: {ranges: [{
        "lo": 0,
        "hi": 89.999,
        "color": "#f05050"
      },
      {
        "lo": 90,
        "hi": 92.999,
        "color": "#DD7502"
      },
      {
        "lo": 93,
        "hi": 100,
        "color": "#41c572"
      }
    ]},
    levelColorsGradient: false
  });
  //refresh gauge when calcvalue changes
  //$(calcValue).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  //  g.refresh($(this).text())
  //})
  window.setInterval( () => {
    g.refresh(Math.random()*100)
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id=calcValue><SpotfireControl id="3321e4c9003142ad83fdb753e6f66605" />
</span>
<DIV id=gauge></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

Our JustGage set up is a little different but we ran into the same issue of calculation not showing up when the dashboard is opened on web browser etc.

The problem (at least what I think) is asynchronous code.
The original code is this:

```
    resource=[
     "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js",
     "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.9/justgage.js"
    ]


    $.getScript(resource[0],function(){
     $.getScript(resource[1],init3)
    })


    //init3 function generates the gauge chart
    init3 =function(){
      var g3 = new JustGage({
        id: "gaugeIRF", 
        value:  $('#calcValueIRF').text(), 
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        levelColors : [  "#73CC06", "#dec121",  "#dec121", "#bd5537" ],
        levelColorsGradient: false,
        symbol:'%',
        pointer: true,
        gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
        counter: true,
        relativeGaugeSize: true,
        title: "IRF Readmission Rate"
      });

      //refresh gauge when calcvalue changes
      $('#calcValueIRF').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
        g3.refresh($(this).text())
      })
    }
```

The init3 function will run and when the browser reads init3, the CalcValue will calculate but likely init3 will finish running before CalcValue is able to give a number back. This is asynchronous and the two processes do not finish in the right order. This is why when the browser opens or you come back to the dashboard, the calculation does not show up.

The solution is to put a function in place. Functions in functions run in the correct order for JavaScript. Here's the working code for me:

```
    resource=[
     "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js",
     "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.9/justgage.js"
    ]


    $.getScript(resource[0],function(){
     $.getScript(resource[1],init3)
    })


    //new function to get the calculated value
    function getValue3(){
      var newValue = $('#calcValueIRF').text()
      return newValue
    }


    init3 =function(){
      var g3 = new JustGage({
        id: "gaugeIRF", 
        value:  getValue3(), 
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        levelColors : [  "#73CC06", "#dec121",  "#dec121", "#bd5537" ],
        levelColorsGradient: false,
        symbol:'%',
        pointer: true,
        gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
        counter: true,
        relativeGaugeSize: true,
        title: "IRF Readmission Rate"
      });

      //refresh gauge when calcvalue changes
      $('#calcValueIRF').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
        g3.refresh($(this).text())
      })
    }
```